# php infinite loop as a solution to session inefficiency

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I'm designing a web app. I started writing using session variables in my php. Now I've discovered that I'll need a solution to make them efficient when I scale up to a multi-server environment. I'm considering AWS's solution, which seems very well integrated into the existing php session variable handling. However, every time I run a SQL script on my database I'll first need variables holding the user's connection details. This looks on the face of it like I'll be at least doubling the number of database queries (as the AWS solution will query their database where the values will be held).

Ever since I realised that I needed persistent variables I've been considering whether it's possible to take a different approach — run only one php script, because if it never ends then I never lose my global variables and thus they become 'session' variables.

I'm thinking of encapsulating all my php code apart from functions in one loop:

```
<?php while (1) {
   $MySQLloginName='fred';   //and more lines like this in no particular order
   //all the rest of my php (except functions) including use of $MySQLloginName etc.
}?>
```

My gut is telling me that this won't work, because as far as I can tell all the ways that a web page can communicate with php, Ajax and Form handling, both accept a url, i.e. the start of a file, not existing running php and not a php function. However if it can be done it seems like it could be pretty cool.

I'm not sure I even understand enough to spot all the potential problems with this approach, let alone how to go about implementing it, so I could really use some input with someone who has a much better understanding of how php works and how it can interact with html, JavaScript and MySQL.

Has anyone tried this or considered and discarded it? Does anyone know of a third party library that might help? I couldn't find any indication of either, which I understand may mean that it's impossible or impractical.

PS. One obvious problem springs to mind, that the php file could be huge (though there may be ways to ameliorate this) and thus load slowly, but I'm prepared to consider that it may be worth it.

Comment: What's wrong with `SESSIONS`?

Comment: load balancing can move your next php file call to another server, which won't have the session.

Comment: @user69911, use external storage for sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your approach would solve except waste RAM and CPU usage. Do you mean try to keep the session open? If so, that won't work since, whenever you do a call to the server (whether it's browsing with HTTP or AJAX), it handles each request separately.

So what can you do?

- If you can modify the load balancing server, it might be worth it to have it record with server it sent the initial traffic to and keep sending it to that server. However, that's not very efficient.
- You could manually assign a cookie with a random string to serve as the session ID and then store that in a MySQL database along with all the items that you would use with `$_SESSION`. This might not be very fast...
- Use an external location for the [session save path](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path). You should be able to set this in the configuration file.

If you can, the first approach would be the best since keeping the data on local RAM is the fastest way to work. I know it's not always equal traffic, but I'm not aware of any other methods besides having each server have a specific task (i.e. large computations, CDN, login, pulling user data from database, etc.).

Comment: Thanks. For now I intend to store my status information in arrays to minimize the number of session calls for it, because if I go with AWS's approach, which turns each session variable use into a query on their server, then I don't want it to end up running any more queries than it has to. While I love considering pushing the edge of the envelope (and I think it helps me learn these languages) AWS's solution looks like the simplest for me to implement right now, as it means I won't have to plan with a more complex method in mind, and minimizing my development time is important.